# replace capital ›ẞ‹ with ›ss‹ when using small caps

Tags: small-caps, capitalization, libertine, german

I like small caps for author surnames.

Until quite recently, capitalized ›ß‹ – a special character that is regularly used in the German alphabet – was replaced by ›SS‹ (in headings, small caps in bibliographies e.g.). Since a capital ẞ has become available in some fonts, it has also become increasingly popular to make use of it, but I don’t like it.

When using the [`libertine`](https://ctan.org/pkg/libertine?lang=en)-package to invoke this font-family for the document, it will automatically turn ß to ẞ when using small-caps (or capitals). Is it possible to avoid this globally (text and bibliography) for ›ß‹ and keep the old setting that simply turned it to ›SS‹?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\bibliography{bibliographie.bib}

\begin{document}

Johann Heinrich Voß\cite{Voss1800} translated Virgil.

\begin{filecontents}{bibliographie.bib}
  @Book{Voss1800,
    author   = {Voß, Johann Heinrich},
    title    = {Des Publius Virgilius Maro ländliche Gedichte übersetzt und erklärt, Vierter Band},
    year     = {1800},
    location = {Altona},
 }
\end{filecontents}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

E.g, this yields the following bibliography-entry:

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe it should be a law that any font providing the utterly ugly ẞ character must provide a stylistic set for replacing it with “SS”.

But you're lucky: not with Linux Libertine, but with its (actively maintained) clone Libertinus. It provides the SS04 feature exactly for this.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @Book{Voss1800,
    author   = {Voß, Johann Heinrich},
    title    = {Des Publius Virgilius Maro ländliche Gedichte übersetzt und erklärt, Vierter Band},
    year     = {1800},
    location = {Altona},
 }
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{scrartcl}

\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[defaultfeatures={StylisticSet=04}]{libertinus}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\textsc{#1}}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

Johann Heinrich Voß \cite{Voss1800} translated Virgil.

\textsc{ß} (just to be sure) fiflffi<<``''>>

ẞ

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Production notes.

- I added an explicit `\textsc{ß}` and an occurrence of ẞ to be sure that the substitution works. Also some of the standard TeX ligatures to see that they are honored.
- I replaced `bibliography.bib` with `\jobname.bib` in order not to clobber my files.
- I also replaced `\bibliography` with `\addbibresource` and you should do as well. By the way, the file name given as argument to `\bibliography` should *not* contain the extension `.bib` (it can with MiKTeX, but it's not portable).

Comment: I get the error message: »Package fontspec Warning: OpenType feature 'Variant=04' (ss04) not available(fontspec)«. Haven’t updated to TL 2021, yet. 
Has this to do with TL 2020? Thank you for sharing my view that ẞ is »utterly ugly«.

Comment: @Kubo You need an up-to-date version of the Libertinus fonts, I'm afraid.

Comment: That did the trick.